# ASP.net MVC page - show in progress and run some task in background

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While I was working in windows application, we show loading in progress message and don't freeze the application and run the required process in background. How to handle the same process in ASP.Net MVC application

For example, I am listing student list in a page. Also there is Upload button which gives more students list. On click of upload button after file s selected, screen will be inaccessible until it completes the process of reading the content from file and convert it into database and refresh the grid. Can we have some background process which will not freeze the page

Comment: Did you read the rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: Please show us that you tried something.

Answer (score 0):

When you have long running task which is taking too much time to complete and the user has to wait until it’s not completed, in this situation you have to write background tasks in your ASP.NET website.

Such as [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (or similar similar open source libraries) used for writing background tasks in your ASP.NET website.

Comment: Is there any inbuilt function available in .net for asp.net MVC to achieve the background task

Comment: We have some options like Task Scheduler and window service which allow us to write background task.But what i feel one more thing is your application needs scaling.You can try Asynchronous Programming in .NET Using Async and Await. or Using the Task Parallel Library in .NET

Comment: Can we use queuebackgroundworkitem to achieve this long running task as background task?

Comment: Yes you can. but before that i would say, try to make your methods async. put async and await and check it still its freezing your application.

Comment: Thank you. I will try async.